# How much memory / processors will cause SQLCLR to fail to load?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I'm considering enabling SQLCLR on our SQL2005 production server, however technet states:

> Computers configured with large amounts of memory and a large number
>   of processors may fail to load the CLR integration feature of SQL
>   Server when starting the server. To address this issue, start the
>   server by using the -g memory_to_reserve SQL Server service startup
>   option, and specify a memory value large enough. For more information,
>   see Using the SQL Server Service Startup Options.

How much memory is "large amounts" in this case? As I realise that this was probably written prior to 2005, so large amounts back then could be the norm now? (same for the large number of processors).